# How to fix YouTube-dl Invalid Parameters on Google Cloud?

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a music bot for Discord. When i open bot in my local, it's work fine but when i do it on Google Cloud it says this:

```
ERROR: mpohX_R0f2I: YouTube said: Invalid parameters.
```

[youtube-dl error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j67qo.png)

I install everything bot's need like ffmpeg, youtube-dl, python, pip etc. 
How can i solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that all the output you get? Can you do any more logging?

Comment: Yes, you can see in this picture: http://prntscr.com/rzfz6m                                                      Other bot commands work good. Like ".help" command. But ".play" command isn't working on Google Cloud.  It's works on my local.

Comment: If it's relevant then share the contents of that image as text in the post itself.

Comment: I add the post. I can't solve this problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GC console to upgrade your **youtube-dl** version as mentioned on the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl):

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

After that, you can check its version being really upgraded. In my case, when I installed it using `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` I got the 2018 version. But using the above method, I got the 2020 version:

[image]